# for making shell script about copy

Tags: svn, shell, awk

I have following files in one directory.

`common_api.h , api.h, abcd.a`

and I have a text file (`copy_directory.txt`) where I have to copy them.

```
src/mw/include/common_api.h
src/mw/include/api.h
src/mw/libs/abcd/abcd.a
```

I want to make a script to copy from one directory to each directory.

I made a command

```
cat svnModify | awk `{print $2}` | xargs -n1 basename
```

but I cannot go further..

Please help.

The result I want to is

```
cp common_api.h src/mw/include/common_api.h
cp api.h src/include/api.h
cp abcd.a src/mw/libs/abcd/abcd.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `awk`

```
% awk -F'/' '{ printf "cp %s %s\n", $NF, $0 }' copy_directory.txt
cp common_api.h src/mw/include/common_api.h
cp api.h src/mw/include/api.h
cp abcd.a src/mw/libs/abcd/abcd.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just shell:

```
while read pathname; do
    cp "$(basename "$pathname")" "$pathname"
done <copy_directory.txt
```